# User input and array analysis

Tags: java, arrays

I have a CountInRange Java program that accepts an integer array, also asks the user to input the minimum and maximum value. Then outputs the count of elements from the array that fall between the minimum and maximum values.

Why is it not working?

```
int [] num ={1, 21, 34, -54, 12, 15, 35};
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int min;
    int max;

    System.out.println("Enter minimum: ");
    min = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter maximum: ");
    max = input.nextInt();

    for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
            if (num[i] >= min || num[i] <= max) {
                count++;
            }                   
        }       
    }
       System.out.println("There are "+count+" elements whose values fall between the maximum and the minimum value");
}
```

Comment: when i typed in minimum is 4 and the maximum is 5, the output is 49.

Comment: Why do you have two loops? It seems like the inner loop is completely useless

Comment: i want total is BETWEEN the minimum and maximum only.

Comment: i tried to remove the loop inside but the the output is 7, that should be 0

Comment: Please refer to my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner for loop is not needed in the least and you should get rid of it.

Also you need to make the conditional and instead of or so it should look something like this:

```
 for (i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        if (num[i] >= min && num[i] <= max) { //AND INSTEAD OF OR
            count++;
        }                          
    }
```

You were testing if the number is >= min OR num  <= max which means if one of these is true it will return true so if your limit was `min = 4` and `max  = 5` and `num = 12` it would return true because `12 >= 4`.